# how to set the width of modal of react-responsive-modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-responsive-modal

how do I set the width of the modal of react-responsive-modal?

https://react-responsive-modal.leopradel.com/#props

```
<div style={{width: '600px'}} >
    <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} closeOnOverlayClick={true}>
        <CreateSubmenu onFormSubmit={this.onSubmenuFormSubmit} editData={editSubmenuData}/>
    </Modal>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be the best it by styling class in css
`.react-responsive-modal-modal { width: 500px }`

You can also use react ref to add style using javascript https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs

EDIT:
I created working code example:
In index.html I added styles:

```
<style>
  .react-responsive-modal-modal {
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-responsive-modal-4tuc1?file=/index.html

Comment: i not sure why the width cant be changed its always width: 100%

Comment: @phongyewtong I added working code example. Please take a look and check if it fullfills your requirements